# Transparent window makes background not redrawing (winxp)

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, transparency, wxwidgets

Im trying to create a popup window with half transparency that renders stuff on itself with DirectX.

The problem is that background does not redraw itself only if rendering is enabled. Redraw happens only when updating (ie when I select a line in a text editor behind my popup window).

Magic begins when my window gets moved to the secondary monitor. Its all ok there. Transparency works perfectly, background redraws constantly. Also if popup steps out of display borders transparency begins to work. (Screenshots below.)

The OS is windows xp SP3 with DirectX 9.0c and NVIDIA graphics card with lastest drivers.

I also tested the program on Win Vista and Win 7 with several different videocards. Works perfectly.

**Creating window**

```
m_popup = new popup(__("pew!"), wxPoint(600, 330), wxSize(250, 250));
m_popup->Show(true);
m_popup->SetWindowStyle(wxSTAY_ON_TOP);
m_popup->SetTransparent(150);
SetTopWindow(m_popup);
```

**Transparency code from wxWidgets (2.8.12)**

```
    bool wxTopLevelWindowMSW::SetTransparent(wxByte alpha)
    {
        typedef DWORD (WINAPI *PSETLAYEREDWINDOWATTR)(HWND, DWORD, BYTE, DWORD);
        static PSETLAYEREDWINDOWATTR pSetLayeredWindowAttributes = NULL;
        if ( pSetLayeredWindowAttributes == NULL )
        {
            wxDynamicLibrary dllUser32(_T("user32.dll"));
            pSetLayeredWindowAttributes = (PSETLAYEREDWINDOWATTR)
            dllUser32.GetSymbol(wxT("SetLayeredWindowAttributes"));
        }
    if ( pSetLayeredWindowAttributes == NULL )
        return false;

    LONG exstyle = GetWindowLong(GetHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE);

    // if setting alpha to fully opaque then turn off the layered style
    if (alpha == 255)
    {
        SetWindowLong(GetHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle & ~WS_EX_LAYERED);
        Refresh();
        return true;
    }

    // Otherwise, set the layered style if needed and set the alpha value
    if ((exstyle & WS_EX_LAYERED) == 0 )
        SetWindowLong(GetHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        // ^ this line seems to cause the problem
        // (tried to make the window transparent manually without wxWidgets' help)

    return pSetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetHwnd(), 0, (BYTE)alpha, LWA_ALPHA) != 0;
    }
```

**DirectX Init**

```
    m_d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = g_size;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = g_size;

    m_d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
            D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &m_d3ddev);

    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
    { 320.0f, 50.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(150, 255, 150, 150), },
    { 520.0f, 400.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(150, 150, 255, 150), },
    { 120.0f, 400.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(150, 150, 150, 255), },
    };
    m_d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(3*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                           0,
                           CUSTOMFVF,
                           D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                           &v_buffer,
                           NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;

    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();
```

**Rendering**

```
    if (m_render)
    {
            m_d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(150, 150, 150, 200), 1.0f, 0);
            m_d3ddev->BeginScene();
            m_d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);
            m_d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
            m_d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 1);
            m_d3ddev->EndScene();
            m_d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

**Screenshots**

1. Transparency fail: http://clip2net.com/s/5IHAyQ
2. Transparency is ok when popup is out of display borders: http://clip2net.com/s/5IHCI3

I also wanted to post a screenshot of how it works on the secondary monitor but I cant neither I  can post images directly to SO because of rep. Just imagine that its just ok on it like it is on the secondary screenshot.

Thank you.

## **PARTIALLY SOLVED, see comments.**

Comment: Just one thing comes in mind: probably, there is some bugs or even design decisions in wxWidgets (it is hard to implement all those features in a cross-platform way), so result is not according to your expectations. You, probably, better rely on Win32 API itself then wxWidgets. So, if you are not planning to use "widgets" (I mean "controls": buttons, text fields, tabs, etc.) and your app is not cross platform, you better write your own window handling code (I believe that your "popup" is just a window without border). It isn't much to code both. Or, at least, try another wrapper library.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well I tried to achieve transparency directly with win32 api. Got the same bug. It seems wxWidgets uses the same implementation as one that I tried. As I stated in my question, the only thing that causes it is setting the WS_EX_LAYERED flag. Unfortunately it is required to make window transparent.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with transparent windows, but, do you use all three of theese flags: `WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`? (Be sure that you don't remove `WS_EX_TOPMOST` with `SetWindowPos()`). Also try to play with `WS_EX_COMPOSITED`. Hope it helps somehow =).

Comment: @Drop Nah, I only use `WS_EX_LAYERED` though I tried different combinations. The bug remains.

Comment: I've tried to make a random Window that utilizes DirectX (a game) transparent with a program. The window left the same trails. So it seems like a driver bug. Cant tell which one it is: the DirectX, the videodriver or Windows itself. I call it.